# Is there any easy way to reverse this hash function?

Tags: python, encryption

I've got the following python method, it gets a string and returns an integer. I'm looking for the correct `input` that will print "Great Success!"

```
input = "XXX"
def enc(pwd):
    inc = 0
    for i in range(1, len(pwd) + 1):
        _1337 = pwd[i - 1]
        _move = ord(_1337) - 47
        if i == 1:
            inc += _move
        else:
            inc += _move * (42 ** (i - 1))
    return inc

if hex(enc(input)) == 0xEA9D1ED352B8:
    print "Great Success!"
```

Comment: This is not *encryption*.  It is more like a hash function, which is something entirely different

Comment: The whole security around hashing, or any encryption, is that it's a one way function, meaning it converts easily but is computationally difficult to find the original from the hash.

Comment: @Tony encryption != oneway function   the whole idea of encrypting something is that you can decrypt it later to get the original back. As opposed to hasing which is what you describe.

Comment: Once you notice that it's summing powers of 42, it's easy to estimate the length of the input - sum up powers of 42 until they're larger than the expected result. Then you should notice that it's converting each character of the input to a number and multiplying with that. So you can calculate the average character value from that. The rest is just a bit of trial and error, tweaking each individual character until the result is just right.

Comment: @IrmendeJong Good point, I was thinking of keys, but the result of encryption is not one-way.

Comment: As Paul Hankin's answer points out, it is just a function that encodes the input into a base 42 number.  It's not even a *hash*.    @Hoe Miller you should get rid of the ``hex`` as well, or make the number you compare to into a string instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's encoding the input in base 42 (starting from `chr(47)` which is `'/'`), and easy to decode:

```
def dec(x):
    while x:
        yield chr(47 + x % 42)
        x //= 42

print ''.join(dec(0xEA9D1ED352B8))
```

The output is: `?O95PIVII`

Comment: perfect, much simpler even than what I did by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bruteforce it. 
Just make a while loop where the input is encrypted by the function until you have the same hash.
But with no informations about the length of the input and so on it could take a while.

Comment: See my answer for the trivial way to determine the required length.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy to crack. The answer is "?O95PIVII".

```
>>> enc("?O95PIVII")==0xEA9D1ED352B8

True
```

The check in your example is invalid by the way, you need to drop the `hex` from it because the literal 0xEA9D1ED352B8 is parsed as an int.

*edit* See Rawing's comment for a hint of how I got the answer. A bit more detail: because its summing powers of 42 based on the index of the char in the string, it's easy to figure out the required length of the input string:  `math.ceil(math.log(target)/math.log(42))` which gives us 9. I then worked my way from the end to the start of the string, because the last character has the most effect on the sum.

Comment: No need to do so, a much simpler way to 'crack' it is given in Paul Hankin's answer.  I think you should flag his answer as the solution really.